# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((32, 1) vs (32, 2))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have altered the code take from [here](https://github.com/jasonchang0/SoBr/blob/master/bin/convNetKerasLarge.py) for binary classification with 1 output neuron

```
import os
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D
from keras import optimizers
from skimage import io
from skimage.transform import resize
from keras.utils import to_categorical
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import random
import glob

n_category_samples = 4000
batch_size = 32
num_classes = 2
epochs = 10

n_image_rows = 106
n_image_cols = 106
n_channels = 3


def train_selfie_model():
    random_seed = 1
    tf.random.set_seed(random_seed)
    np.random.seed(random_seed)

    x_train, y_train = prepare_train_set()

    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.30, random_state=42)

    mean = np.array([0.5, 0.5, 0.5])
    std = np.array([1, 1, 1])
    x_train = x_train.astype('float')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float')
    for i in range(3):
        x_train[:, :, :, i] = (x_train[:, :, :, i] - mean[i]) / std[i]
        x_test[:, :, :, i] = (x_test[:, :, :, i] - mean[i]) / std[i]

    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

    model = compile_model()

    print(model.summary())

    print(y)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

    score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=0)

    print('Test loss: ', score[0])
    print('Test accuracy: ', score[1])

    model_path = os.getcwd() + "/models/saved/selfie-model/"
    model.save(model_path)


def prepare_train_set():
    positive_samples = glob.glob('datasets/drunk_resize_frontal_faces/pos/*')[0:n_category_samples]
    negative_samples = glob.glob('datasets/drunk_resize_frontal_faces/neg/*')[0:n_category_samples]
    negative_samples = random.sample(negative_samples, len(positive_samples))
    x_train = []
    y_train = []
    for i in range(len(positive_samples)):
        x_train.append(resize(io.imread(positive_samples[i]), (n_image_rows, n_image_cols)))
        y_train.append(1)
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print('Reading positive image number ', i)
    for i in range(len(negative_samples)):
        x_train.append(resize(io.imread(negative_samples[i]), (n_image_rows, n_image_cols)))
        y_train.append(0)
        if i % 1000 == 0:
            print('Reading negative image number ', i)
    x_train = np.array(x_train)
    y_train = np.array(y_train)
    return x_train, y_train


def compile_model():
    model_input_shape = (n_image_rows, n_image_cols, n_channels)
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(
        Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', strides=(1, 1), padding='same', input_shape=model_input_shape))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Conv2D(16, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))
    model.add(Conv2D(8, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='relu'))
    # single output neuron
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=.001, momentum=0.9, decay=0.000005, nesterov=False)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model
```

But I am getting following error when running  `train_selfie_model()`

```
ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((32, 1) vs (32, 2))
```

at

```
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

I am new to TF and Keras. Seems like  this is an array dimension mismatch. But how could I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is

At

```
def train_selfie_model():
    ...
    y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
    ...
```

you set `y_train` and`y_test` to one-hot encoding (vectors of shape (2,). But at

```
def compile_model():
    ...
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    ...
```

you have only one output neuron (output of shape (1,)).

So commenting  out / removing following lines will fix your problem.

```
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
```

Comment: how to you suggest to change train_selfie_model without changing single output neuron?

Comment: @user158 It would be helpful if you treat it as a binary classification task instead of a multi-class classification problem. So you could encode the `y_train` and `y_test` with 0s and 1s rather than `[1, 0]` and `[0, 1]`.

Comment: Can I please see necessary changes in code if you do not mind? Are you suggesting to remove `to_categorical(...)` lines

Comment: I don't know how `y_train` and `y_test` look like. Maybe remove `to_categorical` and try it again.

Comment: Also, in the github link you posted, at line 87, the author uses 2 output neurons.

Comment: yes but I want to modify it for a binary classification.

Comment: @user158 OK I understood. Does it work now after removing `to_categorical`? Everything else you did was fine. The activation function was set to sigmoid and loss was set to `binary_crossentropy`.

Comment: Yes It did work thanks that is why I gave you an upvote, since you answer helped even thought it is not complete. mention about removing `to_categorical` so it is complete then I can accept and make you more happy :)

Comment: @user158 My pleasure. If you are interested in the field of deep learning / computer vision. I would also recommend you to take a look at two open courses that are GREAT. 1. https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~justincj/teaching/eecs498/FA2020/ and 2. http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc421_2019/ You won't regret it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231062/discussion-between-user158-and-shihao-xu).

Answer (score 0):

To make a `(32, 1)` array appear as a `(32, 2)`, you can construct a view:

```
arr = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(arr, shape=(arr.shape[0], 2), strides=(arr.strides[0], 0))
```

You could take an even more manual approach:

```
arr = np.ndarray(shape=(arr.shape[0], 2), strides=(arr.strides[0], 0), dtype=arr.dtype, buffer=arr)
```

Both well view the same memory twice, so you should normally treat them as read-only. To copy the data, use any of the following:

```
arr = np.concatenate((arr,) * 2, axis=-1)
arr = np.repeat(arr, 2, axis=-1)
arr = np.tile(arr, [1, 2])
```

Comment: Can you please say how to apply this in the context of code I have posted?

Comment: Place any one of these lines with the appropriately adjusted variable name on a line above the error

Comment: Thanks for the support so far. I have modified ` x_train, y_train, x_test, y_test` with your snippet before fitting the model, now I am getting a new error `ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=2. Full shape received: (32, 2) ` at `model.fit(...)`.

Comment: Sounds like a different question